# Why is it not creating the table Simpsons?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the PHP code that acts as 'action' for another HTML page that has only a form in it.

It doesn't show any errors and after I click submit the message 'Database created' appears, but it's not creating the table 'Simpsons'. Why is this happening?

Please, let me know if I should put more details or comment the code.

```
<?php

$database = 'basedados';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$web = $_POST['web'];

$con = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $database", $con)) {
    echo "Database created";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
}

mysql_select_db($database, $con);
$create_table = "CREATE TABLE Simpsons
                (
                first varchar(15),
                last varchar(15),
                phone varchar,
                mobile varchar,
                fax varchar,
                email varchar,
                web varchar,
                )";
$insert_values = "INSERT INTO Simpsons VALUES ($first','$last','$phone','$mobile','$fax','$email','$web')";
if (table_exists(Simpsons, $database)) {
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
    mysql_query($insert_values, $con);
} else {
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
    mysql_query($create_table, $con);
    mysql_query($insert_values, $con);
}

function table_exists($table, $db) {
    $tables = mysql_list_tables($db);
    while (list ($temp) = mysql_fetch_array($tables)) {
        if ($temp == $table) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

---

Update:

Ok. Thank you all. Now my code looks more like this:

```
<?php

$database = 'basedados';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$web = $_POST['web'];

$con = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $database", $con)) {
    echo "Database created";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
}

$create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simpsons
                (
                first varchar(15),
                last varchar(15),
                phone varchar(15),
                mobile varchar(15),
                fax varchar(15),
                email varchar(15),
                web varchar(15)
                )";
$insert_values = "INSERT INTO simpsons VALUES ('$first','$last','$phone','$mobile','$fax','$email','$web')";

mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
mysql_query($create_table, $con) or die("Error creating table: " . mysql_error());
mysql_query($insert_values, $con) or die("Error inserting values: " . mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I think it looks more clean, although I'm not sure I'm using the `mysql_error()` function correctly.
Thank you again.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What does `echo mysql_error();` say?

Comment: Check for an error on the `mysql_select_db()` call...

Comment: I should just type echo mysql_error(); in any part of the code? I puted it at the end of the code and here's what showed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','h','h','h','h','h','h')' at line 1. These 'h' are the variables that came from the form.

Comment: You should check for `mysql_error` after every mysql call. And not just while in development.

Comment: `table_exists(Simpsons, $database)` Simpson should have quotes around it. But thats likely not the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One comma to much, and you need to specify the length of the varchar-fields

```
CREATE TABLE Simpsons
            (
            first varchar(15),
            last varchar(15),
            phone varchar(xx),
            mobile varchar(xx),
            fax varchar(xx),
            email varchar(xx),
            web varchar(xx)
            )
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a single quote missing in your table before $first:

```
INSERT INTO Simpsons VALUES ($first','$last','$phone','$mobile','$fax','$email','$web')
```

But to be honest, without a good error report it is hard to define which things are mistakes in your code and which are typos in your post.

BTW: Have a look at http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: What Stegeman is hinting at is that your code is wide open to a SQL injection attack. You should wrap all of your strings in mysql_real_escape_string before using them in a query. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

**Why do you call `mysql_select_db($database)` when only a few lines before you called `mysql_select_db($database, $con)`?** I would drop it.

Not an answer but a refactoring suggestion I couldn't fit into a comment:

```
if (table_exists(Simpsons, $database)) {
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
    mysql_query($insert_values, $con);
} else {
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
    mysql_query($create_table, $con);
    mysql_query($insert_values, $con);
}
```

could just become

```
// connect statement dropped
if (!table_exists(Simpsons, $database)) {
    mysql_query($create_table, $con);
}
mysql_query($insert_values, $con);
```

or even eliminated altogether by modifying your creation query's first line to read `CREATE TABLE Simpsons IF NOT EXISTS` and replacing the above lines with:

```
mysql_query($create_table, $con);
mysql_query($insert_values, $con);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe for first try to execute this code via cli or phpmyadmin if you don't know how to use [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) (see examples on page its really easy)